# Cant connect to smpt server

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, debian

I can't connect smtp external server.

`org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.yandex.ru, 465; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out). Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.yandex.ru, 465; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out); message exception details (1) are: Failed message 1:`

[ufw status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm47A.png)

Locally all work.

Comment: Hi, you might want to add some code or details behind your request. Also check out some guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're unable to connect to the smtp server at all.

Try this:

1. Open the port(465) in your firewall, since `Connection timed out` means that the client is unable to connect to the server on that port probably because it is blocked by the firewall of either the server or the client.
2. Turn off the other security options (e.g. Antivirus, etc.).